# Creating custom info windows on Google Maps version 3 with data array from JQuery Output

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

As the API for Google Maps version 3 is still evolving, I do not wish to use any plugins. My original script for version 2 works perfectly to display custom infowindow that appears when a marker is clicked and disappears when the map region is clicked. The new API introduces an object google.maps.OverlayView, which I have difficulty using in conjunction with JQuery. A sample of my original code is shown below:

```
function Results(json) {
    var L = json.output.length;
    var website = json.web;
    if (L > 0) {
        for(i=0; i<L; i++) {
            var listing = json.output[i];
            addLocation(listing, website);
        }
    }
}

function addLocation(A, B) {
    var point = new GLatLng(A.lat, A.lng);      
    var icon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
    icon.image = 'images/' + A.mks + '.png';
    var M = new GMarker(point, icon);
    map.addOverlay(M);

    GEvent.addListener(M, 'click', function(){
        showInfo(M, '<A href=\"site.php?ID=' + A.id + '\">' + A.name + '</A>');
    });
    GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
        hideInfo();
    });

    showResult(A, B);
}

function showInfo(M, text){
    var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(M.getPoint());
    $('#info').appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));
    $('#info').show()
        .css({ top:markerOffset.y, left:markerOffset.x })
        .html(text);
}

function hideInfo(){
    $('#info').hide();
}

var Q = 'search.php'; // an array is output in Json format
$.getJSON(Q, Results);
```

The closest example I can find is: http://www.tdmarketing.co.nz/blog/2011/03/09/create-marker-with-custom-labels-in-google-maps-api-v3/ which is still quite far off from what I have in mind.

I am not sure if anyone has an idea of transforming the above so that it can work with API version 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    window.x = e.pageX;
    window.y = e.pageY;
});
var hover_div;
var hover_offset_x = 0;
var hover_offset_y = 0;

var createHoverDiv = function(_txt){
    hover_div = $("<div>",{text:_txt,"class":"hover_div"});
    hover_div.css({
        "background":"#fff",
        "position":"absolute",
        "top":window.y+hover_offset_y,
        "left":window.x+hover_offset_x
    })
    $("body").append(hover_div);
};
var killHoverDiv = function(){
    hover_div.remove();
};
var displayResults = function(_json){
    for(var i=0;i!=_json.length;++i){
        addLocation(_json[i]);
    }
};
var addLocation = function(_obj){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(_obj['lat'], _obj['lng']),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        createHoverDiv(_obj['point_name']);
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        killHoverDiv();
    });     
};
var data_array = $.parseJSON('[{"point_name":"point_a","lat":"-32.783129","lng":"151.74312"}]');
```

displayResults( data_array ); to get it working. I just put some sample data in the JSON bit for now.

```
enter code here
```